# Parse json property to a specific type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My starting point is something like this (simplified here) :

```
    private object GetPropValue(JToken token, Type type)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(token["prop"].ToString(), type);
    }
```

Usage :

```
var value = GetPropValue(JObject.Parse(someJsonWithAPropertyNamedProp), typeof(someTypeFoundByReflection));
```

This works, except then the type is string.

According to the doc, ToString() of a JValue should return a JSON, **but when the JValue is a type string, the value returned is not a JSON, but rather a simple string, not wrapped with escaped quotes.**

Therefore, I get an exception :

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.

What is the best way to achieve this ? Add a condition if the JToken is of type string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JToken` already has a built-in `ToObject()` method to do what you want.  If you change your `GetPropValue` method to use that instead of converting back and forth from JSON, everything should work fine:

```
private object GetPropValue(JToken token, Type type)
{
    return token["prop"].ToObject(type);
}
```